# Why doesn't my JFrame repaint when I set a new Synthetica theme?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, themes, synthetica

I just set my applications theme to Synthetica Alu Oxide but some reason the JFrame doesn't repaint but another Synthetica theme will repaint the JFrame.

This is what mine looks like.

http://i.imgur.com/SOBDTs4.png

This is what its suppose to look like.

http://www.jyloo.com/images/screenshots/syntheticaAluOxide/democenter2.png

```
    public MainPanel() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setTitle("Asteria 3.0 NPC Definition Editor");

    try {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(new SyntheticaAluOxideLookAndFeel());
    } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    components();       
    frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
    JTabbedPane tab = new JTabbedPane();
    tab.addTab("Information", informationTab());

    tab.addTab("Bonuses", bonusTab());
    tab.addTab("Animation", animTab());
    tab.addTab("Property", propertiesTab());
    tab.addTab("Miscellaneous", miscTab()); 

    frame.getContentPane().add(tab);
    //frame.add(this);
    frame.setSize(500, 600);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);     
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Swing GUI objects should be constructed and manipulated *only* on the [event dispatch thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html), *after* you've invoked `UIManager.setLookAndFeel()`.

```
try {
    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(new SyntheticaAluOxideLookAndFeel());
} catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        …
        frame.pack(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
});
```