# JComboBox item does not show in JTattoo lookAndFeel

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, look-and-feel

I use JTattoo LookAndFeel for my swing application. JComboBoxes in my app do not paint correctly. They do not show the selected item text. It just shows an arrow at the middle of JComboBox. When I click on combo, it shows the dropdown list, but it does not show the selected item. How can I fix that?

EDIT: It works in other lookAndFeels.
My GUI objects are constructed and manipulated in the `event dispatch thread`. but the comboboxes are corrupted.

[image]

Comment: Does it work in other look and feels?

Comment: Verify that your application is [correctly synchronized](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html), for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30841894/230513), and does _not_ artificially constrain the layout, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12532237/230513).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why doesn't my JFrame repaint when I set a new Synthetica theme?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30841389/why-doesnt-my-jframe-repaint-when-i-set-a-new-synthetica-theme)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized that I had changed the lookAndFeel after `mainframe.setVisible()`. I should had changed id before `mainFrame.setVisible()` to take the best effect.