# Different Results When Setting Nimbus LAF

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, look-and-feel, nimbus

I'm a bit confused with what is happening with my GUI. In my program, I wanted to overwrite Nimbus' default font with my own custom font, so of course, I have this code in my program:

```
try {
        NimbusLookAndFeel laf = new NimbusLookAndFeel();
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(laf);
        laf.getDefaults().put("defaultFont", courier);
} catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(GUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

That's all fine and dandy except it doesn't overwrite all of the font. Just the font on the title borders. Example:
[image: Screenshot of program with UIManager code in program]

Now, if I set the Look and Feel via VM Options in Netbeans, I get this result:
[image: Screenshot of programm with UIManager code in program AND VM Options set]

If it's of any help, these are the VM Options I am using:

```
-Dswing.defaultlaf=javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel
```

My main concern with this is that when compiling into a 'fat jar' and running on another computer, the VM options don't seem to stick and I am left with the crappy looking first screen shot. So can anyone tell me why this is happening? Maybe offer up some kind of workaround or fix. Thanks!

EDIT: The nice looking theme (screenshot 2) doesn't seem to work outside of netbeans at all

Comment: Possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30841389/230513): "Swing GUI objects should be constructed and manipulated only on the event dispatch thread, _after_ you've invoked `UIManager.setLookAndFeel()`."

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Will try, though I question the possible duplicate.

Comment: Did the suggested approach fix the problem?

Comment: No. For some reason, the only thing that worked was setting the L&F to nimbus via -D flag, then setting it to nimbus again programmatically

Comment: That is emblematic of the same underlying problem.